# Cluster data based on some threshold points

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

How can I cluster a data based on some threshold values.
I have some points like 2, 1,0.5. I need to find the nearest elements of each of these 3 points and need to cluster into 3 groups.How can I do that in matlab. Please help me.

If I use some points(like centroids) for clustering[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7sXj.png).
Assuming the 2 is a centroid and finding the elements near to that point and clustering the dense region of the point 2.
(calculate the distances from all the centroids
classify the data into the nearest cluster)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please provide more details. As it stands, it's hard to undersand your question. Ideally include a small example with input and desired output

Comment: Thank you sir.I edited my comment. I have a dataset how can I attach the dataset here?